Creating Fade-Out Laser Light Rays Without light spots in Blender
I'm trying to create a scene that includes laser or light rays similar to the example images provided, but I want these rays to avoid casting any reflections on surrounding surfaces. Here's what I've tried so far:
Volume Scatter Method: I placed the entire scene within a volume scatter and used spotlights to simulate the rays. This provided the ray effect, but reflections still appeared on the walls, which I want to avoid.

Cone with Principled Volume Method: I modeled the rays using a cone with a Principled Volume shader. This method allows for ray control but creates a clean cut at the end of the ray, which I don't want. I'd prefer a smooth, gradual fade-out at the end, with the ray appearing brightest near its origin.

Could someone suggest a way to achieve laser light rays in Blender that:
Don’t cast any reflections on walls or other surfaces.
Have a smooth fade-out at the end of the ray.
Start bright at the origin and gradually diminish along the length of the ray.

Any tips on shader setup or alternate methods would be greatly appreciated!

Do you want it to be in Cycles or Eevee ? With Cycles it would be simple to not cast light in the scene with a Light Path node. Also, are you talking about lasers (red line), or just spot lights (white cone) ?

If you use a Texture Coordinate node in the shader editor, with the Generated output you can get a gradient from 0-1 on the local XYZ axis for your object. Then use the Z output multiplied over your volume density and emission values and it will create the fade out effect. You can use a color ramp to edit the falloff.



Omg thank you so much! This is great and solved my problem!:)

Awesome! If this answer works can you accept it as the answer so it gets removed from the unanswered questions queue?
